# GRUB installation failed on Bionic Beaver

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, 18.04

i am trying to install Bionic Beaver from a USB stick. At the end of the installation process, the error message reads

The grub-efi-amd64-signed package failed to install into /target/. Without the GRUB boot loader, the installed system will not boot.

Sorry, I have no clue what further information you would need in order to help me but I am glad to supply any info you would consider relevant.

Best,
toby

Comment: if your BIOS settings is set to UEFI mode while installing Ubuntu.. you have to create EFI Partition first and then ext4 mounted to /. if you have only created ext4 / without EFI Partition, that error comes and you cannot boot.

Comment: Boot-Repair may be able to fix issue, but it does not create partition(s) if needed. Best if someone reviews your configuration. Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info